# My S-Rank recruits go missing after I fulton them. Whats going on?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I'm on mission 30 and I've already fultoned a few S-Rank soldiers out; however, in my roster, I can't find them at all. Am I missing something? My iDroid is up to date on upgrades and so is my fulton, so I have no idea why they are vanishing and I can't seem to find a solution searching with Google.

Comment: They're likely Boasters, no?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the brig? I am sure all new recruits go there first.

Comment: Come to think of it, I interpreted the question as "I have Fultoned some S-ranks on *this specific mission*; why aren't they showing up?", but if you Fultoned them earlier, checking the brig would be a good idea, as would not assuming Boasters that say S-rank really are S-rank.

Comment: Indeed check the brig

Answer (score 3):

As no additional info are provided, this is the likeliest answer:

The soldier you fultoned were shown as S rank, but were Boaster. Which mean while you see them as S rank on the field, they really are A rank, or even B rank. (rumors say they could even be as worse as C rank). When they get in the Brig, their real stats are shown, and as such don t appear as S rank anymore.

Answer (score -2):

People don't actually arrive at Mother Base until you hit a checkpoint. When they do, you'll get an "Extraction Flight Arrived at Mother Base message", and anything you picked up or Fultoned will enter Mother Base's inventory. You can trigger a checkpoint by leaving the map area (though it's not clear where the triggers are) or by continuing the mission until you hit a milestone that gives you a checkpoint.

Comment: Most of the time in my experience, returning to the ACC also triggers the "Extraction Flight Arrived at Mother Base" message (though it might not do so if you are in combat).